# I get an Assertion Failiure ((elemSize() == sizeof(_Tp)) in C++ OpenCV when trying to access values of a histogram

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram

When I am trying to access the bin values of a generated histogram of a greyscale image, I get this assertion failiure:

Error: Assertion failed (elemSize() == sizeof(_Tp)) in cv::Mat::at ... opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp, line 943

This is the Code Fragment that throws the failiure:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        
        hist.at<float>(i) = (hist.at<float>(i) / pixelAmount) * 255;
        
    }
```

My main problem is that i dont really understand the problem associated with the assertion failiure

I looked up the OpenCV documentation for [Histogram Calculation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dbc/tutorial_histogram_calculation.html) and they are accessing the histogram values the same way.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Which datatype is `hist`,  i.e. which array type? Or how is it created?

Comment: @M.Spiller The histogram is a cv::Mat object of type CV_8U

Comment: Then it should be `hist.at<uchar>(i)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @M.Spiller yes this works but i am unable to perfom calculations this way

Comment: Provide a proper [mcve] -- that code fragment is absolutely useless on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you got your `hist` `Mat` from another API call, so its type can't be affected at creation time.

The `at<T>()` method requires you to know the element type of the Mat (say, `CV_8U`), and to use that same type (`uint8_t`) in the access.

There are two ways to solve this situation:

1. get the scalar value (`uint8_t`), convert the scalar value so it suits your calculation, write back (`uint8_t`) a coerced value
2. convert the entire `Mat` to `CV_32F`, which is equivalent to `float`, and then do your operations

First option:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    hist.at<uint8_t>(i) =
        (static_cast<float>(hist.at<uint8_t>(i)) / pixelAmount) * 255;
}
```

Second option:

```
hist.convertTo(hist, CV_32F);
// now do your calculations with at<float>()
```